# How to determine individual contribution when data is aggregated by team

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I want to know the individual contribution of each salesperson in terms of actual sales where the dataset I have aggregates sales data by sales "team".

The dataset looks as follows:

```
Month | # of Sales | SalesPerson1 | SalesPerson2 | SalesPerson3
1 | 25 | Fred | Susan | Tom
1 | 12 | John | Wayne | Connor
2 | 16 | Fred | John | Wayne
2 | 11 | Susan | Tom | Winona
3 | 34 | Connor | Susan | Tom
```

Is there a way to predict the individual contribution of any given salesperson based on the data above where the membership of any given sales team can change from one month to the next?

I want to be able to say that for any given sales person, they close x # of sales per month.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to DataScience.SE! I think you need more information; e.g., an itemization of the sales, and knowledge about the types of items each salesperson sells. Is this really all you have?

Comment: I wish. There are other data point like "Type", "Sales Method", etc... but these are all aggregated at the same level that "# of Sales" is as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Two alternatives

**TrueSkill**:

You might want to try a variant of [TrueSkill](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/trueskilltm-a-bayesian-skill-rating-system/). As Wikipedia says:

> Factor graphs are used to "pack up" each team into $(\mu ,\sigma )$
>   pairs on which the update formulas are run; the skill updates are then
>   correctly distributed to each player.

Here's the [TrueSkill paper](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/trueskilltm-a-bayesian-skill-rating-system/) with more details. From the abstract:

> The new system tracks the uncertainty about player skills, explicitly
>   models draws, can deal with any number of competing entities and can
>   infer individual skills from team results. Inference is performed by
>   approximate message passing on a factor graph representation of the
>   model.

**Simple Regression**:

You can try to set this up as a multivariate regression problem. Inputs are tuples representing who was involved in the sale, outputs are # of sales. So something like this, assuming tuples are (Fred, Susan, Tom, John, Wayne, Conner, Winona):

```
(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 25
(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), 12
(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0), 16
etc...
```

Now each person's coefficient should be proportional to their contribution, assuming no interaction effects.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  What are your thoughts about reorganizing the dataset so that each row represents the total sales by salesperson where the features are the sales people (values the # of times each person was on team).  So for Fred, y = 36 for example.

Comment: What do you mean by "no interaction effects"?  Because it would seem there will be given that sales teams can be mixed (e.g. Fred is part of both teams 1 and 3 above though his partners were different).

Comment: No interaction effects means that, for example, John and Wayne don't create more or less value together than apart. A negative interaction effect might occur because they don't like each other, so they hinder each others efforts. A positive interaction effect might occur if they help each other out more than they do other team members.

Comment: Tried using simple regression but some of the coefficients are negative (and no one can have negative sales; the least they can have is 0).  How might I resolve this issue?  thanks

Comment: Hahaha, that means that an individual's contribution is negative. That is, whenever that individual is part of the team, the team's sales go down.

Comment: Some folks won't be excited to see that.  So it doesn't seem there is any way to specifically predict the # of sales per person ... only a relative positive or negative feel based on the coefficients.

Comment: I think the coefficients are the sales per person. The people who have negative coefficients are generating negative sales. But pay attention to the error on your coefficients. If the coefficient is -0.1 + or - 5.0, it's not clear how much you can conclude

Comment: sorry to be the noob here.  but as I'm training the model against the entire dataset (only have 75 examples), how do I determine the error of my coefficients?  btw, I'm using sklearn.  Thanks again

Comment: Google should be able to point you to the right docs for that

Comment: Do you live on here TJ? :)  Will do.  On the TrueSkill side I didn't see anything that can infer actual sales for each individual ... but it does seem helpful to assign a rating to each individual.  In that respect, it is very similar to using regression to get a feel about each person rather than a prediction on the number of sales they will make on a given team.  Sound right?